# How to show Play from start/Resume Playing on tvOS AVPlayerViewController

Tags: tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Usecase:
Video is watched by user to some time, than user interupts it. Bookmark is saved. Than later on I want to offer user to continue from last watched position.

Is it possible to get that behavior in AVPlayerViewController?

This screen:
https://i.imgsafe.org/b69204ca24.jpg

I have seen this in youtube app and Apple build in TV app.

Comment: Do you find the solution yet?

Comment: not yet. As workaround I use mine UI with two buttons, but it is not very elegant considering the fact there is better solution just not documented.

Comment: Youtube app is less than 1 MB in Apple TV. I believe it uses TVML to create this app, which is totally different than Swift.

Comment: good point. it really might be TVML..this makes me sad.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timing when the video get interrupted, and then use the seek function to start playing from that same time frame:

[Seek](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1386108-seek)

Comment: Well, that is known. Question is how to get that UI. If you check that screenshot, you will see that it is inside AVPlayerViewController. I could only provide chapters..and have chapters when you swipe down..to jump where you want, but there is more elegant solution. Somehow, it is possible to display that alert inside AVPlayerViewController and question is about how to do that.

Comment: posted error report to Apple. Got email that it is duplicate. Hope we get it sometime in the future.